# Prevent child element hovering from breaking parent hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, hover

So let's say I have a parent div element that has an img child and that I want to execute some code when the parent element is hovered.

```
<div class="parent">
    <img src="link_to_some_image" />
</div>
```

The issue here is that when the child img is hovered, the parent "hover state" breaks. How can I make it so that the parent keeps its hovered state even if its child elements are hovered?

Here is an example jsfiddle, try hovering on the empty space and then on the image http://jsfiddle.net/omrf0dxe/

Thanks a lot!

Edit: The img children is an example, it might be other type of elements as well like divs,links etc

Edit2: Ok, apparently the solution was to use mouseleave instead of mouseout when binding the "exit" event.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are listening to the events `mouseenter`/`mouseout`.

You want the events `mouseenter`/`mouseleave`:

[**Example Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/0brwvcd8/)

```
$(".parent").on("mouseenter mouseleave", function () {
   $(this).toggleClass('hovered'); 
});
```

---

As an alternative, you could also add `pointer-events: none` to the child `img` element in order to essentially remove mouse events from the element:

[**Updated Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/k0wj3g6s/)

```
.parent > img {
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

---

Depending on what you're trying to achieve, you may not even need JS, though.

Just use the `:hover` pseudo class.

[**Example Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/qpfg4m8k/)

```
.parent {
    width:400px;
    height:400px;
    background:blue;
}

.parent:hover {
    background:red;
}
```

Comment: Thing is I don't always know if the child is going to be an image, or multiple elements like divs, images etc.
Is there a general approach to this solution that isn't children type specific?

Comment: Well the solution was pretty simple, I had to use mouseleave instead of mouseout.
However, I didn't know about the pointer-events usage so thanks a lot about that and for your help :)

Answer (score 1):

Pretty basic solution, not sure if you want yours to stay toggled, but I would attack it with a add/remove class.

```
$('.parent').hover(
       function(){ $(this).addClass('hovered') },
       function(){ $(this).removeClass('hovered') }
)
```

http://jsfiddle.net/omrf0dxe/7/

Comment: It was weird why this was working and mine wasn't, so I noticed that I was using mouseout instead of mouseleave, which was the error. Thanks!

Comment: No problem man, just tested your mouse leave theory and that one works too, so you have 2 solutions now :)